# How do you share data between two different apps?

Tags: android, android-intent

im working on my mobile app and im trying to send data (text) from my guest application to my admin application. These applciations are two seperate projects in android studio and im getting an error on the guest side of the application which states `error: cannot find symbol variable txt` where as on my admin application i get a different error saying `Error running 'app': Default Activity not found` which im assuming has got to do with the admin applications manifest file.

This is my code for the guest application where the txt error is coming from.

```
package com.example.prototype;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CleaningService extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cleaning_service);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Cleaning Service");

    Button button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button5:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            break;

    }
}


public void sendMessage(View v)
{
    String message;
    message = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

This is the error from my admin application project.
Androidmanifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.prototypeadmin">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".GuestTab"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".guestrequest"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_guestrequest"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AdminMenu"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".GuestRequests"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Admin application code:

```
package com.example.prototypeadmin;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;


public class GuestTab extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabItem tab1, tab2, tab3;
public PageAdapter pageradapter;

TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guest_tab);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    Intent i = getIntent(); // added object intent to receive data
    String action = i.getAction();
    String type = i.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) // Shares Data
    {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type))
        {
            String getMessage = i.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            txt.setText("Guest Request :"+getMessage); // checks validation of string getMessage
        }
    }

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Guest Request Panel");



    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabMode);
    tab1 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.Tab1);
    tab2 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.Tab2);
    tab3 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.Tab3);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    pageradapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageradapter);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                pageradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                pageradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 3) {
                pageradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));



}
}
```

The outcome of it should be that the message once sent from the guest application should appear on the admin application.

xml file of where the text is going to be sent from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:context=".CleaningService">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="399dp"
    android:layout_height="299dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter text here.."
        android:shadowColor="#F8F1F5F4"
        android:textColor="#F8F1F5F4"
        android:textColorHighlight="#F8F1F5F4"
        android:textColorHint="#F1E9E9"
        android:textColorLink="#F8F1F5F4"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:id="@+id/et1"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:text="Send"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
    android:layout_width="161dp"
    android:layout_height="189dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/mopp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your admin application has no launcher `Activity` (ie: one with the ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER in the manifest). This means that after you install the app you can not start it. If you do not start it, the app remains in a "stopped state" and Android will not automatically start it. This is probably why the admin app fails to start.

---

The second problem is your error **"cannot find symbol variable txt"**

This is probably caused by this code in `sendMessage()`:

```
message = txt.getText().toString();
```

Here the compiler is complaining that `txt` is an unknown variable. You probably want to do this:

```
message = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
```

In this case using the variable `v` which is the `View` passed into the `sendMessage()` method. You need to cast `v` as a `TextView` (I'm assuming it is a `TextView`) so that you can call `getText()` on it.

I'm making a bunch of assumptions here, including that `sendMessage()` is called from a button click using `onClick` in the layout.xml.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. I've additionally added action.main and category.launcher to my manifest. The Admin applciation is launching which i think is a good sign. Although im getting an error with the code `message = v.getText().toString();`. Now its saying that it cannot find the method getText()

Comment: You need to cast `v` as a `TextView`. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Hello David. In my xml i am now calling the method `sendMessage()` to call `getText()` i want to ask would i have to do that on my admin side of the application or on the guest application? 

Also for the admin applications manifest file do i just keep main and launcher activity on there in the intent filter or would i need to add more activities to that field? I've updated my code.

Comment: You misunderstood. What you did to the manifest is wrong. You need to have one `<intent-filter>` that contains ONLY ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER. You also have a DATA entry there which should NOT be there. This `Activity` will then show up on the HOME screen and you MUST run the app at least once manually before the app will be able to be started by your guest app. Since your guest app is launching an `Intent` with ACTION=SEND, you will need to have an `<intent-filter>` with ACTION=SEND and DATA specification so that the admin app will be run when the guest app calls `startActivity()`.